# Referencing Business Requirements Document (high level reqs) with Build Backlog (low level reqs)

Tags: backlog

We currently have "N" Business Requirement Documents that need to have functional requirements checked off as we progress through a large project.

These aren't particularly granular and, in some cases, only scratch the surface of expected or intended functionality. So, we've defined the actual solution to build in a JIRA backlog.

Does anyone have a process or tool or even a little advice on how to bridge the gap between these very different but intrinsically linked groups?

Apologies if this question isn't specific enough, and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to explain which business requirement causes a FR to exist, how would you do that? Do the business requirements have an identifier attached to them, or would you constantly repeat the title/content of the requirement?

Comment: Why can't you use Jira as the source of truth for requirements? It provides states for tracking the status of the requirement, it provides linkage to other tickets (which may be other functional requirements or derived requirements), and you can use tools like Confluence and BitBucket to generate documentation, dashboards, and traceability to code.

Comment: I think this may be the first time I've seen someone here actually use the correct capitalization of JIRA. Kudos.

Comment: To add a little context here. A BRD Req might suggest "Form to upload user info with the following fields", but to actually build this we're proposing components built in Javascript, CMS, Proxy Caching, and then passing into Amazon SQS services, before finally being plopped into a CRM for final use behind the scenes. We do have Epics defined, but they're more functional groupings, and this is just one of perhaps 20 Epics in the overall solution. Key thing is though, even the Epics aren't aligned to the BRD Reqs. Like I say, they're actually functional groupings to build. My head really hurts.

Answer (score 1):

Epics.

Epics are designed to be higher-level that Stories. JIRA automatically displays which Epic a given Story belongs to, and can list all Stories within a given Epic.